# How do I fix issue with goapp serve

Tags: google-app-engine, go, environment-variables

```
$ goapp serve app.yaml

goapp serve: unable to find dev_appserver.py
```

so I checked:

```
$ which dev_appserver.py

/Users/darianhickman/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py
```

My suspicion is that the google app engine launcher tool breaks `go_appengine` links to `dev_appserver.py`.
Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: My `dev_appserver.py` is also in my google cloud sdk path but `goapp serve` still works for me.  Not sure if it's relevant, but my `google-cloud-sdk/bin` dir is before my `go_appengine` dir in my path.

Comment: So I had to struggle through a couple overlaps of path.  Installing go sdk then installing go app engine sdk creates a duplicate go installation that causes issues when they aren't the same version.  Also google cloud sdk and go app engine sdk create duplicate installs of dev_appserver.   I guess it's too much to ask the SDK teams to make their installs factor in checks for these existing dependencies.

Comment: Btw, it's resolved now but not sure how I resolved it since it was a while back.